# Trying to populate my highcharts pie chart with variable

Tags: variables, highcharts

I must be missing something very stupid, because my pie chart works when I put a number in, but not a variable. The code for my chart is below. The two variables were taken from PHP variables, but they do work, because if I call an alert on the variables right before I make the chart, they do pop up. It's just as soon as I put them as data in the chart, the chart won't show up.

What am I missing here?

```
$('#space').highcharts({        
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Used vs. available diskspace.'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Over all customers.'
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Magnetic disks',
            data: [
            {
                name: 'Free space',
                color: '#2674c7',
                y: $free,
            },
            {
                name: 'Total space',
                color: '#ac2d38',
                y: $total,
                sliced: false,
                selected: true
            },
            ]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it was something sort of silly as I suspected:

the PHP variables I assigned to the js variables were strings...

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
y: $total,
```

you should use

```
y: <?php echo $total ?>,
```

Becuase you cannot common js / php variables.

Comment: As I said, I had already assigned the PHP variables to js variables and checked them with an alert(). The problem was that they were assigned as strings, instead of integers, so I just did a parseInt() and it's fine now.